# How to pull a BitBucket repository without access to hg

Tags: python, mercurial, bitbucket

I was wondering if it was possible to pull a private mercurial repo to a server without access to hg. I have SSH access, but do not have the ability to install HG. I was thinking some kind of Python script that used http access or something, but I wasn't sure. I was also thinking this might only be possible with public repos. I am currently hosting the projet on BitBucket. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What good would getting the repository be if you don't have mercurial installed and can't install it?

Do you instead mean get the files in a specific revision?  If so you can easily do that using:

```
wget https://username:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/REVISIONHASH.zip
```

I'm pretty sure you can put user/pass in the URL in the standard HTTP way.

Comment: Yeah, I've just confirmed that user/pass in the URL works fine for private repos on bitbucket.

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended method](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3225/commanline-download-compressed-tip) for pulling a private Mercurial repo from Bitbucket is answered over [here at a more recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955290/wget-compressed-tip-from-bitbucket-mercurial/7972374#7972374).

Here's the command:

```
curl --digest --user username:password https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/tip.zip -o test.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have mercurial available locally then you may as well pull the tarball instead, available behind the "get source" option towards the top-right corner of various pages, underneath "Forks/Queues".

Comment: The problem with that was since it is a private repo, it won't let me download it via wget. I'd have to upload the tarball on the server via FTP anyway which is what I'd like to avoid.