# Wget compressed tip from Bitbucket (mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, wget, bitbucket

We would like to use mercurial for web development, but we can't (and don't want to) install mercurial on a shared host. We try to use wget as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082107/how-to-pull-a-bitbucket-repository-without-access-to-hg), but I get 401 error. 
Credentials and link are correct (modified for security).

Is there a way to download source from command line?

Is this bug or am i doing something wrong?

Response below:

```
$ wget _http://xxxx:yyyyyyy@bitbucket.org/username/repo/get/be51983f6357.zip 
--2011-10-31 00:26:50--
http://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/repo/get/be51983f6357.zip 
Resolving bitbucket.org... 207.223.240.182, 207.223.240.181 
Connecting to bitbucket.org|207.223.240.182|:80... connected. 

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
301 Moved Permanently Location: https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/get/be51983f6357.zip [following] 
--2011-10-31 00:26:51-- 
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/get/get/be51983f6357.zip 
Connecting to bitbucket.org|207.223.240.182|:443... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
401 UNAUTHORIZED Authorization failed.
```

## Take 2:

Thanx for help... i changed http to https and user user & password attributes:

Browser works fine, Wget does not...

```
$ wget --verbose --user=XXXXX --password=YYYY  https://bitbucket.org/ekku/REPO/get/aabbccddeee.zip
--2011-10-31 18:27:10--  https://bitbucket.org/ekku/REPO/get/aabbccddeee.zip
Resolving bitbucket.org... 207.223.240.182, 207.223.240.181
Connecting to bitbucket.org|207.223.240.182|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Failed writing HTTP request: Bad file descriptor.
Retrying.
```

## Take 3:

I also tried curl, but i get error message: 
    Forbidden (403)
    CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: Try hitting the HTTPS url directly. you're hitting HTTP, and wget's most likely NOT carrying over the url-embedded credentials through the redirect.

Comment: Use the `--user` and `--password` command line options instead.

Comment: I got it working with curl:  


    curl --digest --user username:password https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/tip.zip -o test.zip  
  
Answer from bitbucket:https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3225/commanline-download-compressed-tip  

Hi Esa,

We don't actually support basic auth for downloads of source bundles.

You need to use digest auth. Also, from what I understand, wget has a bug with its digest auth implementation.

You can use curl with the --digest flag and the -o flag to specify your output file.

Cheers,

Dylan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it working with curl:

```
curl --digest --user username:password https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/tip.zip -o test.zip
```

Answer from Bitbucket: [Issue #3225 - Commanline download compressed tip](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3225/commanline-download-compressed-tip)

> Hi Esa, We don't actually support basic auth for downloads of source bundles. You need to use digest auth. Also, from what I understand, wget has a bug with its digest auth implementation. You can use curl with the --digest flag and the -o flag to specify your output file. Cheers, Dylan

Answer (score 0):

You should not use bitbucket over `http`; always use `https`. That should get rid of the additional redirect that you're seeing.

Also use the command line options `--user` and `--password` to specify the authentication for `wget`; SSL probably doesn't allow to add user and password to the URL because the server part (between `://` and the next `/`) is sent to the server in plain text.